# 3rd Party Control Will Not Install On Windows 8/IE 10

Tags: .net, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, txtextcontrol

We have a .NET Framework 2 web-based app that uses the txTextControl text editor.  We have a built-in script that sets CASPOL for our users.  We are getting an "Access Denied" error when we try to install this control on Windows 8/IE 10 machines, as shown in the image below.  I have installed the 3.5 Framework (which also installs 2 and 3), but still no joy getting the control to install.

Any ideas and advice are greatly appreciated, as more and more of our users are wanting to use our system on Windows 8 machines!

Mike

[image: screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've published some information here to help with this because of the .NET 4.5 changes (which is on Win8)

Check out:
http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/blog/archive/20130119/

```
Since .NET 4.5, the security model has been changed and hosting these controls
is blocked in Internet Explorer by default. The previous behavior can be 
restored by setting the EnableIEHosting value of the registry subkey
HKLM/SOFTWARE/MICROSOFT/.NETFramework to 1.
```

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I've seen that article and tried that.  There was no EnableIEHosting key, but I added one.  It is a type of REG_SZ and the value is 1.  I still get the same error.

Comment: Try it as a DWORD (most numbers are) also note at the bottom it differs for a 64 bit machine: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieitprocurrentver/thread/1342e167-8016-4a75-99bf-4d11d01d9bb1

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've now tried entering the key as a REG_SZ, DWORD and QWORD, and I get the same error.  Does the machine need to be rebooted after applying the key?

Comment: Ah....I added both keys from your links as DWORDS, and now it's working.  THANKS!!!